# A,B are rings with unity and $\phi:(A,+,\cdot)\rightarrow (B,+,\cdot)$ is a ring isomorphism, prove that $(A^{*},\cdot)\cong (B^{*},\cdot)$

Tags: linear-algebra

The motivation was to show that the set of $n\times n$ matrices with matrix multiplication is isomorphic to the set of linear maps from an $n$-dimensional vector space to another $n$-dimensional vector space with composition of two functions as operation.

We know that if $A$ is a ring with unity, we can define the set $A^{*}$ such that $A^{*}$ contains all elements that are invertible with respect to the defined "multiplication".

Can someone help me how to approach the proof of this statement?

Since I already know that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. I only need to show that $\phi(A^{*})=B^{*}$, (because then I know hom+sur $\Rightarrow$ inj) how can I do that?

Comment: It's not true that a surjective homomorphism is injective

Comment: Yes you are right the argument is wrong but the conclusion is right nevertheless because we already know $\phi$ is injective then $\phi_{|A^{*}}$ must be also injective

Comment: In short, if two objects are isomorphic, then "everything" defined from them corresponds via that isomorphism

Comment: Did someone ask you to prove this? If not then you can immediately conclude that $\phi(A^*)=B^*$ on base of the fact that the sets are both completely determined by the ringstructure.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is regarding your title.

Assume that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism of rings and let $a \in A^{\times}$. Then we get
$$1 = \Phi(1) = \Phi(aa^{-1}) = \Phi(a)\Phi(a^{-1}) = \Phi(a)\Phi(a)^{-1},$$
such that the image of $a$ is a unit. This means we have $\Phi(A^{\times}) \subset B^{\times}$. Can you show the other inclusion? Start by taking a unit from $B$, choose a preimage (you can do that since the map $\Phi$ Is surjective) and use the injectivity to show that the preimage was a unit in $A$.

Comment: How do you know that $\phi(1)=1$? Sorry I got it it is because $\phi(a)=\phi(a\cdot 1)= \phi(a)\cdot \phi(1)$

Comment: Because $\Phi$ is a homomorphism of (unitary) rings. Do you not use this definition?

Comment: wait how do we know that $1$ is unique? When I say A;B is a ring with unit I mean there exists one element $1_A,1_B$ such that for all $a,b\in A,B\quad$ $a1_A=a=1_Aa$ and $b1_B=b=b_1b$

Comment: Yes but that implies that it is unique. Assume we have two identities $1$ and $1'$. Then we get $$1 = 1 \cdot 1' = 1',$$ where the first equality holds since $1'$ is an identity element and the second since $1$ is an identity element.

Comment: I take $b\in B^{*}$ then there is an $a$ such that $\phi(a)=b$ then $b\in \phi(A)$. Why do you say that injectivity is needed for this proof?

Comment: Because you need to show that the preimage is not only in $A$, but in $A^{\times}$.

Comment: $b\in B^*$ because of surjectivity there exists an $a$ such that $\phi(a)=b'$, because od injectivity we know there is only one $a$. We have to show that $a\in A^{*}$, i.e. there must exist an $a'$ such that $aa'=1$. Because $B^{*}$ is a group there exists ecax. one $b'\in B^*:bb'=1$. Let$ a''$ be the unique preimage of $b$ such that $\phi(a'')=b'$ then $1=bb'=\phi(aa'')=\phi(1)$. How can I follow from that that $a'=a''$?

Comment: Oh I did not see that you editet your first comment. Your argument there does not work since you cannot be sure that the image of $1$ is a unit.

Comment: Start with the equation $1 = \Phi^{-1}(1)$ and now substitute the $1$ in $B$ by $bb^{-1}$ and use the homomorphism property. Then you get an inverse for the preimage of $b$  In the same way as my answer.